# How to store orginal frame of UIView subclass loaded from storyboard automatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a subclass of UIView which is has a property called originalFrame.

I want this class to store the original it's original frame value after it loaded from the storyboard it is apart of.

I have overridden the awakeFromNib method:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.originalFrame = self.frame;
}
```

This works if the view of the view controller it is apart of is not resized right after to fit the screen size.

However, the view controllers in my storyboard are all for the iPhone 4-inch screen, so when the app runs on an iPhone 3.5 inch screen, awakeFromNib is called before the view controller's view is resized to fit the 3.5 inch screen. If my subview is not anchored to the top, then the originalFrame property won't reflect its frame after the resize.

I was able to override layoutSubviews to get the frame property after the view controller's view was resized, but this method is called other times too and I have no way of knowing if it is for the initial resize to fit screen, or something else.

Is there any way to do this without having to set this property manually on a case by case basis in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is already set if you set it in awakeFormNib to `CGRectZero` and check in `layoutSubviews` if it is `CGRectZero`. Only set the frame in `layoutSubviews` if it is `CGRectSubviews`.